# Java Clustering Library

Tags: java, math, cluster-analysis

I am looking for a light weight clustering library in java. I don't need 100s of clustering algo in that library just 5 to 7 algo would be fine for me.

I am sure, you are going to ask: "what kind of algo do you need and for what purpose" :). I just need to do classification of my data with the help of clustering. For example K means.

P.S: I know about weka but I don't want to use it as it is not specifically for clustering only.

Comment: what do you mean with clustering? Is weka sth. for you?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your answer. and what is sth?

Comment: Note for future reference... in software development, "clustering" usually means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_%28computing%29

Comment: @skaffman not really, see data mining or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: @agazerboy sth. means something. for weka take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29
So, do you mean the data mining technic? ah, okay I read your edit ...

Comment: @Karussell: I said "usually".

Comment: @skaffman That's entirely dependent on the context. And cluster analysis, "usually" refers to data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: what's with all the downvotes on this question?

Comment: @lynxoid Im not sure, but i think every answer seemed to get multiple downvotes within a few days. Pretty odd.

Comment: @lynxoid the question is clearly **off-topic**, and the answers are largely **link-only answers** (which is a reason to downvote, some links here are even dead): http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Links were not dead 6 years ago. A link to a "lightweight clustering library" is a reasonable answer to the question. Good luck to SO w/ their purge of old Q&As.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [org.apache.commons.math4.ml.clustering.KMeansPlusPlusClusterer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/ml/clustering/KMeansPlusPlusClusterer.html) in Apache's [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/). It has a number of clustering algorithms implemented, although I'm not sure if K-means is one of them.

Another option might be to take a look at [Knime](http://www.knime.org/), an Eclipse based workflow editor. This includes a number of clustering primitives you can use as part of a workflow, including K-means.

Comment: For those interested, JUNG has k-means clustering: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/util/KMeansClusterer.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some open-source clustering algorithms in Java available here, available under the GPL. Requires the Java Colt library (for matrices).
http://open.trickl.com/

Comment: I'm gonna try this, looks like the one for me :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is also [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), an open-source university project similar to WEKA, but with the focus on cluster analysis and outlier detection instead of machine learning algorithms.
It's pretty advanced, uses index structures for efficiency, and has at least a dozen clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If Scala also works for you, then you might want to check this version of KMeans in Scala:

https://github.com/wspringer/kmeans

A related blog post is here:

http://nxt.flotsam.nl/k-means-clustering.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want some basic clustering algorithms in Java, you can check my software:

http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/

It offers an implementation of KMeans and a hierarchical clustering algorithm.

The other algorithms offered are for pattern mining. Totally, there are 47 algorithms. But only 2 for clustering.  Another thing: there is a simple GUI for launching the algorithms.

Answer (score -1):

Apache Mahout implements many clustering algorithms, via Hadoop. It's a little heavy for what you want, but: http://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/syntheticcontroldata.html

Also you might be able to dig out and adapt the user clustering code from Mahout's TreeClusteringRecommender class, which uses clustering for recommender engine purposes.

Comment: i read about it. Its a very huge and complex one :(

Answer (score -1):

[Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) software has several plugins that implement clustering algorithms for networks and numerical data (Nemo, MCODE, clusterMaker, and so on). All plugins are open-source.